# suzuki savage the electric died the battery is good

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki

I have a Suzuki Savage and the battery is good, but when I had it at the store it lost electric at the solenoid. It has power in the off position but not in the on, diminished power in the park position, and no power in the on position - no  lights no nothing, although I have power at the fuses and the fuses are good.

What can be the problem? This happened all of a sudden. thanks

Comment: Start by checking for dirty battery terminals, damaged broken battery cables and proceed to check fuses / fuse box supply and ignition switch.

Comment: "diminished power in the park position" : how did you determine this?